# Get form values using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting values from a form using Angular JS. The validation works great but I'm doing something wrong with the controllers or submit function.

Here's my current code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController as loginCtrl" >
  <h1>LOGIN</h1>

  <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && loginCtrl.loginCheck()" novalidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="login.email" required />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="login.password" ng-minlength="8" required />
    <button type="submit" class="right">LOGIN</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

**Angular JS**

```
app.controller('LoginController', function(){

  this.loginCheck = function(){
    console.log(login.email);
  };

});
```

At the moment I'm just looking to log the form results in the console but I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: login is not defined...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject `$scope` service instead of using `this`.

Like this instead:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope){
  $scope.login = {};

  $scope.loginCheck = function(){
    console.log($scope.login.email);
  };

});
```

John Papa had recommended an approach where you could create Controllers methods using `this`. However, I personally I do see the benefit of deviating from the standard but you want to read more about this approach here is the article that explains it:

http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Comment: That should be `$scope.login.email`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work for me. I was initially following the video course tutorial through the Angular website (actually on Code School) which doesn't use $scope. After trying your method, I don't get the logged result, I just get nothing in the console.

Comment: Ah I've worked it out. I also had to remove the `loginCtrl` from `loginCtrl.loginCheck()` on the form element. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did not have the proper syntax for `controllerAs`. Neither $scope nor controller as is the "standard" either, as the other answer suggests. Both work.

See the below example using your code, though I am not sure you intended for the submit button to not call a method ... but that is easy to extend.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController as loginCtrl" >
  <h1>LOGIN</h1>

  <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && loginCtrl.loginCheck()" novalidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="loginCtrl.email" required />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="loginCtrl.password" ng-minlength="8" required />
    <button type="submit" class="right">LOGIN</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Angular JS

```
app.controller('LoginController', function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.email = '';
  vm.loginCheck = function(){
    console.log(vm.email);
  };

});
```